# T extends ChangeEvent<any> ? void : (e: string | ChangeEvent<any>)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, formik

I am using a custom formik component like this in my screens:

```
 <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                  <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.form}>
                      <FieldInput
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                        handleBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.phoneNumber}
                        fieldType="phoneNumber"
                        icon='phone'
                        placeholderText='49152901820'
                      />
                      <ErrorMessage
                        name="phoneNumber"
                        render={(msg) => (
                          <Text style={styles.errorText}>{msg}</Text>
                        )}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                      <Button
                        onPress={handleSubmit}>
                        Search
                      </Button>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
```

I get a TypeScript error on handleChange and handleBlur that:

```
Type '{ (e: ChangeEvent<any>): void; <T = string | ChangeEvent<any>>(field: T): T extends ChangeEvent<any> ? void : (e: string | ChangeEvent<any>) => void; }' is not assignable to type '(e: string) => undefined'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'e' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<any>'

FieldInput.tsx(9, 3): The expected type comes from property 'handleChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FieldInputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

The field inputs are supposed to be strings and I don't think I should change ChangeEvent's type to string. 'any' is also not a good option. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe error caused by this line

```
onChangeText={handleChange(fieldType)}
```

because handleChange(fieldType) is a string, converting it to function like

```
onChangeText={(e: any) => handleChange(fieldType)}
```

might fix the error

Comment: It doesn't fix the issue, unfortunately